# Combination in if condition with several input parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Function has a few parameters like
`@a int, @b int, @c int , @d int`

it only need to allows, values are not null
either 
@a, @b,  @c, @d, and combination of @a + @b

i tried it with but it's allow other combinations too like `@a + @c`

`if((@a is not null) or (@b is not null) or (@c is not null) or (@d is not null) or ((@a is not null) and (@b is not null)))`

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: You mean, if e.g. `@c` is not null, then the other three *must* be null?

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
IF
    (
        @a IS NOT NULL 
        AND 
        @c IS NULL
        AND 
        @d IS NULL
    )
    OR
    (
        @b IS NOT NULL
        AND 
        @c IS NULL
        AND 
        @d IS NULL
    )
    OR 
    (
        @c IS NOT NULL
        AND 
        @a IS NULL
        AND 
        @b IS NULL
        AND 
        @d IS NULL
    )
    OR 
    (
        @d IS NOT NULL
        AND 
        @a IS NULL
        AND 
        @b IS NULL
        AND 
        @c IS NULL
    )
```

Or this:

```
DECLARE @validate INT;
SELECT @validate = SUM(validate) 
FROM 
    ( 
        SELECT CASE WHEN @a IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END validate
        UNION
        SELECT CASE WHEN @b IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END 
        UNION
        SELECT CASE WHEN @c IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 2 END 
        UNION
        SELECT CASE WHEN @d IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 2 END 
    ) n;

IF @validate BETWEEN 1 AND 2
```